# I am trying to run my flutter app and I get this error every time , just upgraded flutter to 2.10.0 version

Tags: flutter, maven, kotlin, dart, gradle

```
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\06445d7ee3d674db365da5b7e383aeec\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04-api.jar!\META-INF\window_release.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.  
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\185d46b6321985f52dcc07c04b9e0199\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.31.jar!\META-INF\kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\57fff25d753f492b2e9dfa8a7a25a127\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar!\META-INF\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7ed1fc227d449123990dfe95b91bbf13\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!\META-INF\kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.      
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\989d7c521cad3a1e2e82ee6a7a836f54\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar!\META-INF\kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: error: module was 
compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9c675fcd73ec0913dfa5836b73d5959f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04-api.jar!\META-INF\window-java_release.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cdd51607f1d98bcc689bce197d763afe\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar!\META-INF\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
C:\Users\asabahy\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ced2a85cd1d4e10ca7b42bb11579f9f7\jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar!\META-INF\kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: error: module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             ٨٠٫١s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

after running flutter doctor , I got this issue

```
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = https://maven.google.com/
```

Comment: I didn't try it yet , instead i , uninstalled flutter then installed it again , and now everything is working perfectly

Comment: yes bro , your answer worked , thank u a lot for your help .

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Sabahy I dunno why bit I can't see the answer you got by other users, can you please tell me how you solved this issue?

Comment: Hi , @Elia Mirafiori , okay first the problem cuz of ext.kotlin_version , so where u can find it , and how u can solve it ? okay , first go to android/build.gradle file and u will find this line  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'  inside buildscript{} so just change its version to ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32' and save then run your app again and every thing will work.

Comment: Super, later I will try to fix this thank you